# ¿Cómo añadir reglas css nuevas (o modificar existentes) al framework BULMA?

Tags: html, css, sass, bulma

Entiendo menos que más la sintaxis css y cómo aplicar estilos a divs y demás (muy básicos), pero me resulta un poco difícil de entender "por qué" en ocasiones se aplican ciertos estilos y otras no. Sé que usando un framework ya escrito debería simplificarlo pero cuando intento "modificar" esos estilos y añadir o cambiar cosas para un elemento en particular en ocasiones funciona y otras no.

Mi objetivo para no modificar el estilo ya existente global seria "extender" ese estilo añadiendo o cambiando algunos atributos.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="column"></div> <-- Este seria es estilo por defecto

<div class="column paddingvertical"></div> <-- Este seria el mismo pero con un padding diferente
```

El codigo css (por ejemplo) seria:

```
paddingvertical {
padding-top: 3em;
}
```

...y este añadido a un .sass donde he cambiado las variables oportunas al cual tiene importado bulma como última linea.

He probado poniendo un . delante del estilo css, probado `.column .paddingvertical {`, probado poniendo el estilo después de importar bulma en lugar de antes y algunas cosas más que ya no recuerdo, pero no consigo que se refleje el cambio en el div. Entiendo que el estilo `column` me está sobrescribiendo el mio, pero me cuesta entender cual seria la manera correcta de añadir más estilo a uno ya existente de forma local.

Sin embargo este estilo antes de importar bulma...

```
.hero img {
transform: rotate(22deg)
}
```

...si que me gira la imagen que ponga en el hero, lo cual es todavía más confuso.

Está claro que tengo un problema conceptual, por lo que no busco solución a "este" problema sino una norma o regla lógica que me permita comprender donde está el problema y solucionar este y los que me surjan en adelante.

Comment: Lee sobre [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad), mientras más específica es una declaración, mayor peso tiene a la hora de aplicar. Si vas a modificar estilos provenientes de otra fuente, lo ideal es cargar primero ese archivo y después el que usas para "personalizar".

Comment: He estado buscando en google y mirado con anterioridad esa pagina que dices pero o soy muy obtuso o me parece demasiado academico y no consigo "entender" el concepto. Seguiré mirando, gracias :)

Comment: Has probado usar el !important en el estilo. Debes tener 2 cosas. primero que el css de dicho framework se cargue primero y segundo que tenga tus estilos el !important. Prueba así a ver si te funciona como esperas

Comment: Si, de esa forma si que funciona (muchas gracias), pero por lo que he estado leyendo se debería de evitar usar !important y ser más especifico, ¿no? Esa es la respuesta que ando buscando

Comment: No uses `!important`, espera unos minutos, estoy preparando una respuesta.

Comment: Sin problema, llevo con esto mucho tiempo así que no tengo prisa y estoy aprendiendo por mi cuenta así que te lo agradezco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero es conocer cómo se deben declarar las reglas en css:

- Las etiquetas se declaran por nombre, sin signos:

  - `div {}` Asignará el estilo a todos los elementos con esta etiqueta
  - `p.una-clase {}` Aplica a todos los párrafos que tengan la clase `<p class="una-clase"></p>`
- Para definir reglas por ID se antepone `#`:

  - `#boton {}` Aplica a un elemento con la ID especificada `<button id="button"></button>`
- Para definir reglas por clase se antepone `.`:

  - `.pad-vertical {}` Aplica a todos los elementos que tengan la clase, por ejemplo: `<li class="pad-vertical"></li>` o `<section class="pad-vertical"></section>`

Ahora, lo que te comenté en cuanto a orden de declaración y [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad), se aclara con algunos ejemplos y comentarios de porque sí o porque no aplican:

```css
/* No aplica porque se declaró antes de .column y no es muy específica */
.paddingv1{
    background:#8c8;
    padding:30px 10px;
}

/* Aplica porque es más específica, incluyendo las dos clases deseadas */
.column.paddingv2{
    background:#8c8;
    padding:30px 10px;
}

.column {
    display:block;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}

/* Aplica porque se declaró después de .column */
.paddingv3{
    background:#88c;
    padding:30px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="column">Estilo por defecto</div>

<div class="column paddingv1">Estilo sobreescrito, no aplica</div>

<div class="column paddingv2">Estilo con mayor especificidad</div>

<div class="column paddingv3">Estilo declarado después de .column</div>
```

Entonces, para modificar estilos de otra fuente (Bulma, por ejemplo) necesitas cargar primero los estilos originales y después los tuyos:

```
 <link href="bulma.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="mis-estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Cuando algo no funcione, solo asegúrate de ser específico en tus declaraciones para que tengan mayor importancia y evitas el uso de `!important`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, mejor explicado :)